# ImportError: No module named can but it's there according to pip list in ubuntu 18

Tags: python, pip

I have in python the error:

```
ImportError: No module named can
```

but the strange is that when I check it with pip list in the environment all these libraries are installed:

[Screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puM4X.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, it tells me that the can library is not found, but when I check it with pip list, they are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some libraries were only available for some python versions